# Changing table structure on the fly using SymmetricDS

Tags: symmetricds

My setup consists of a master and a slave node connected to a MySQL and Oracle DB, respectively. The slave node already successfully pushes rows added to a table to the master node. However, when I add a column to the source table nothing changes at the target table. So far I figured out that

```
INSERT INTO `symmetricds`.`sym_table_reload_request` (`target_node_id`, `source_node_id`, `trigger_id`, `router_id`, `create_time`, `create_table`, `delete_first`, `processed`, `last_update_time`) 
VALUES ('master', 'client', 'ALL', 'ALL', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), '1', '0', '0', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
```

should cause an update of the target schema. However, this only works when I restart the symmetricDS slave node (which sends the data). That is, adding the column, restarting and then performing the insert works and the server's logs confirm that the XML containing the table structure contains the new column. Yet, when I skip the restart the XML shown in the server's logs still misses the new column. Is there a way to make this work without a restart?

Comment: This sounds like a bug.  You can enter bugs here: http://www.symmetricds.org/issues

Comment: What version of SymmetricDS is this?  It does look like the tables structure is read before sending the command to alter the table, so I would not expect a restart of the source server to be required.

Comment: I'm using version 3.11.7.

Comment: Are you saying that the client may be sending deprecated table structure information? I've tried setting the client's cache.table.time.ms to 30 seconds. However, even after waiting for 30 seconds after issuing the alter-table statement the XML I see at the server side log still does not contain the new column.

Comment: After adding the new column you might need to sync triggers prior to sending the reload.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Hey, that worked! I changed the sync triggers cron timing so that it runs every minute and indeed the new column popped up on the server side. Do you know a better way of starting the sync trigger job, e.g. manually after a given table manipulation?

Comment: Also, there is a problem with the cron-timed sync trigger solution. If the sequence is 1) Alter table, 2) Issue reload request 3) Scheduled sync trigger, i.e. the reload request is issued before the trigger synchronization the change in table structure will never be pushed to the server unless another reload request is issued.

Comment: I think you can update the last_update_time on the sym_trigger row and the next routing run the trigger that was updated will be sync'd

Comment: This did the trick! (So my posted answer below)

Answer (score 1):

With the help of chenson42 I was able to make this work. Let's say you have the folowing trigger for table "my_table"

```
insert into sym_trigger
(trigger_id,source_catalog_name, source_table_name,channel_id,last_update_time,create_time)
values('my_trigger','my_catalog','my_table','default',current_timestamp,current_timestamp);
```

Now you add a column:

ALTER TABLE my_catalog.my_table ADD hacky_works varchar(40);

Then, in order to synchronize the chagned table structure with the master note run the following lines:

```
UPDATE sym_trigger SET last_update_time=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() where trigger_id="my_trigger";

INSERT INTO sym_table_reload_request (`target_node_id`, `source_node_id`, `trigger_id`, `router_id`, `create_time`, `create_table`, `delete_first`, `processed`, `last_update_time`) 
VALUES ('master', 'client', 'ALL', 'ALL', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), '1', '0', '0', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
```

Note that in this example 'master' and 'client' are the configured names of the source and target node.